# Iptables v1.6.1 can't initialize iptables table `filter' Ubuntu 18.04 Bash Windows

Tags: bash, ubuntu, filter, firewall, iptables

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows Bash:

```
uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-M87DGAS 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #112-Microsoft Thu Jun 07 22:57:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I need to open some port with:

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: initcaps
>       [Errno 2] iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table 
>       does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
>       Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

I get the same error by typing:

```
iptables -L
```

I've already upgrade my kernel with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get full-upgrade
```

I've tried to reboot the system but it didn't work.

How can I initiate the iptable filter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the Microsoft WSL page on github.com, iptables isn't supported.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/767

There is a uservoice page for requesting support at

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/32025199-support-iptables

Comment: I'd note that the WSL page on github.com says that WSL now supports iptables in very recent versions, though it is evident some people are still having problems.

Comment: Yep, I am trying to run docker on my Windows Bash, and I am having the same error.

Answer (score 6):

Windows restrict that command in WSL without authorization from administrator.

You just have to run WSL on `CMD/Powershell/Ubuntu.exe` as administator, then try this command again:

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

I tested on WSL v1, but it should also work on WSL v2.

Comment: I have been searching for solution for 3 days now and this is the answer, to run as administrator. Thanks so much for this. Btw this is all the things I did for others looking for solution: Run cmd in elevated mode
Powershell
Ubuntu.exe
update-alternatives --config iptables
(select legacy)
iptables -L -v